# How to build a table of contents (in HTML5 / Vue) from a set of data that follows a Tree Structure with Array of Ancestors (mongoDB)?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, vuejs2

I am trying to build a table of contents from a dataset from mongoDB and the data follows this pattern (as described in the mongDB docs [HERE](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/) - Model Tree Structures with an Array of Ancestors):

```
{
  _id: "fAAe3od48Pwgxer7v",
  title: "Deskside Support",
  catSlug: "deskside",
  catLevel: 5,
  parentId: "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL",
  parentSlug: "infra",
  parentTitle: "Infrastructure",
  ancestorsId: [
    "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT", "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt", "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL"
  ],
  ancestorsSlug: [
    "it", "governance", "structure", "infra"
  ],
  ancestors: [
    "Info Tech", "Governance", "Structure", "Infrastructure"
  ]
},
```

I am using Vue.js and so I was able to create a table of content using some methods and looping through the array, like so:

```
<div v-for="cat in findTopLevelCats('root')" :key="cat._id">
  {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
  <div v-for="cat in findChildCats(cat._id)" :key="cat._id">
    {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
    <div v-for="cat in findChildCats(cat._id)" :key="cat._id">
      {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
      <div v-for="cat in findChildCats(cat._id)" :key="cat._id">
        {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But as you can see, my code is very ugly and it does not address an n-depth level of categories. Also I cannot use this code if I ever wanted to create a set of `<option>`s for a `<select>` element.

The ideal way would be to reconstruct the array of data by putting each one in its correct place. Because the data set currently coming from mongoDB is not in order.

See the code sample I have attached for a sample of the dataset. The Vue v-for loop only goes to 4 levels deep. For me, the ideal array to be rebuild should order the elements in a flat array like this:

```
- Level 1 - Info Tech
-- Level 2 - Governance
--- Level 3 - Structure
---- Level 4 - Infrastructure
----- Level 5 - Network
----- Level 5 - Security
----- Level 5 - Deskside Support
---- Level 4 - Enterprise Applications
--- Level 3 - Risk Management
-- Level 2 - Third Party
- Level 1 - Human Res
-- Level 2 - Entitlement
```

I have looked at other types of code to build trees (with nested arrays of children - like [HERE](https://typeofnan.dev/an-easy-way-to-build-a-tree-with-object-references/)) but I don't think this is what is needed.

So the question is, given a dataset like in my code example (see data from 'catDataFromDB'), how would you re-arrange the array to order each object in the order as above. (Note: sorting at this time is not required but could be optional, if feasible). Codes on how to achieve the above objective are very welcome (as I have tried several times on my own in javascript/vue and have failed miserably, even crashing my browser cause I went into an infinite loop :( ).

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      catDataFromDB: [{
          _id: "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5",
          title: "Info Tech",
          catSlug: "it",
          catLevel: 1,
          parentId: "root",
          parentSlug: "root",
          parentTitle: "root",
          ancestorsId: [

          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [

          ],
          ancestors: [

          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT",
          title: "Governance",
          catSlug: "governance",
          catLevel: 2,
          parentId: "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5",
          parentSlug: "it",
          parentTitle: "Info Tech",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt",
          title: "Structure",
          catSlug: "structure",
          catLevel: 3,
          parentId: "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT",
          parentSlug: "governance",
          parentTitle: "Governance",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it", "governance"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech", "Governance"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL",
          title: "Infrastructure",
          catSlug: "infra",
          catLevel: 4,
          parentId: "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt",
          parentSlug: "structure",
          parentTitle: "Structure",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT", "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it", "governance", "structure"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech", "Governance", "Structure"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "TsBBkMG65oNvg3rng",
          title: "Human Res",
          catSlug: "hr",
          catLevel: 1,
          parentId: "root",
          parentSlug: "root",
          parentTitle: "root",
          ancestorsId: [

          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [

          ],
          ancestors: [

          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "ops6v6AgFdxfg9bZH",
          title: "Entitlement",
          catSlug: "entitlement",
          catLevel: 2,
          parentId: "TsBBkMG65oNvg3rng",
          parentSlug: "hr",
          parentTitle: "Human Res",
          ancestorsId: [
            "TsBBkMG65oNvg3rng"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "hr"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Human Res"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "XGgGbtJ9L5LNHuNKK",
          title: "Third Party",
          catSlug: "third_party",
          catLevel: 2,
          parentId: "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5",
          parentSlug: "it",
          parentTitle: "Info Tech",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "W6q6j3r9uKmkrnzHh",
          title: "Enterprise Applications",
          catSlug: "ent_apps",
          catLevel: 4,
          parentId: "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt",
          parentSlug: "structure",
          parentTitle: "Structure",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT", "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it", "governance", "structure"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech", "Governance", "Structure"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "zppQ6Fpkeve4eL72E",
          title: "Risk Management",
          catSlug: "risk_management",
          catLevel: 3,
          parentId: "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT",
          parentSlug: "governance",
          parentTitle: "Governance",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it", "governance"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech", "Governance"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "vwtrsYjfgRbQEmLw8",
          title: "Network",
          catSlug: "network",
          catLevel: 5,
          parentId: "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL",
          parentSlug: "infra",
          parentTitle: "Infrastructure",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT", "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt", "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it", "governance", "structure", "infra"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech", "Governance", "Structure", "Infrastructure"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "fyWzrx4azEDfCyPK4",
          title: "Security",
          catSlug: "security",
          catLevel: 5,
          parentId: "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL",
          parentSlug: "infra",
          parentTitle: "Infrastructure",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT", "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt", "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it", "governance", "structure", "infra"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech", "Governance", "Structure", "Infrastructure"
          ]
        },
        {
          _id: "fAAe3od48Pwgxer7v",
          title: "Deskside Support",
          catSlug: "deskside",
          catLevel: 5,
          parentId: "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL",
          parentSlug: "infra",
          parentTitle: "Infrastructure",
          ancestorsId: [
            "462WigdWJPaAdF3G5", "XtFEipeusYpWtEcoT", "LMRaqDJ7Tah4mXLAt", "fdJfFkoeH2B6AkMTL"
          ],
          ancestorsSlug: [
            "it", "governance", "structure", "infra"
          ],
          ancestors: [
            "Info Tech", "Governance", "Structure", "Infrastructure"
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    findTopLevelCats(rootVal) {
      return this.catDataFromDB.filter(obj => obj.parentTitle === rootVal);
    },
    findChildCats(parentCatId) {
      return this.catDataFromDB.filter(obj => obj.parentId === parentCatId);
    }
  },
  filters: {
    lead: function(catLevel, char) {
      return char.repeat(catLevel);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Building a table of contents (in HTML5 / Vue) from a set of data that follows a Tree Structure with Array of Ancestors (mongoDB)</h1>
    <p><a href="https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/" target="_blank">See model here</a></p>

    <p>Given a set of data (for example categories) from a mongoDB collection that follows the pattern of a tree structure with an Array of Ancestors, how would you display a table of contents for such categories?</p>

    <h2>Find Root categories</h2>

    <p>Finding the categories at the top root level, or starting at any level is relatively easy.</p>

    <div v-for="cat in findTopLevelCats('root')" :key="cat._id">
      {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
    </div>

    <p>Find 4 levels down of the categories from the root level</p>

    <div v-for="cat in findTopLevelCats('root')" :key="cat._id">
      {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
      <div v-for="cat in findChildCats(cat._id)" :key="cat._id">
        {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
        <div v-for="cat in findChildCats(cat._id)" :key="cat._id">
          {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
          <div v-for="cat in findChildCats(cat._id)" :key="cat._id">
            {{cat.catLevel | lead('-')}} Level {{cat.catLevel}} - {{cat.title}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>But what about an n-depth level? Also, the above will not work for a "select" element that will contain "option" tags.</p>

    <p>If I had an ordered array, I could loop through the array and generate the "option"s for the select element.</p>

    <div style="height: 500px;"></div>


  </div>
</body>
```